# Adjust the scroll when the table is resized

Tags: swift, tableview, scrollview

I am working with a kind of shopping cart and for this I am using a table view with buttons to add products to my shopping cart.

[image]

When the user adds a product to their shopping cart, a view appears at the bottom with the total of their purchase. and when the shopping cart is empty the view disappears and the table adjusts to the size of the view.

This adjustment is made by changing the value of the constraint at the bottom of the table

```
@objc func hideView(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.bottomDistance.constant = 0 //TableView constraint bottom
    })

}
@objc func showView(){
    let padding = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.bottomDistance.constant =  100 + padding
    })
}
```

Everything works well, the constraint is updated but the cell that is in the place of the view is hidden, you have to move it up so that it can be visible.

[image]

In what way can I adjust the scroll so that it goes up automatically and the entire cell is aligned to the bottom view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your subclass should be a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController. That way you can create a UIView so the height of the UIView is view.frame.height - (your button height). You then add your tableView as a subview in that UIView.
Then set the bottom constraint of the button to view.bottomAnchor. That way, your button stays on the bottom of the page and since your tableView is inside your UIView that you created, it won't reach the button so it just scrolls all the way inside that UIView.

Do something like this:

```
let tView = UIView()

then in viewDidLoad():
tView.backgroundColor = .clear

view.addSubView(tView)

//constraint your tView leaving room for the price button at the bottom of the view
tView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leadingAnchor, right: view.trailingAnchor, heightConstant: view.frame.height - (priceButton.frame.height))

tView.addSubView(tableView)

//anchor table view to top, left, right, and bottom of tView

view.addSubView(priceButton)

priceButton.anchor(left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.trailingAnchor)
```

So in this case you have two views in your main view. The UIView - tView, and the price button. Now your tableView will be in your tView so it doesn't interfere with the button. Hope this helps.